# "Сейчас" и "теперь"

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли смысловая разница между словами "сейчас" и "теперь"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на мой взгляд, теперь указывает на что-то уже случившееся, а сейчас на будущее - сей-час - в течении этого часа, к примеру.

Answer (score 1):

Смысловой я не вижу.
Кузнецов, правда, насчитывает у "сейчас" шесть значений против одного у "теперь", но большой разницы у этих шести значений нет.

Стилистически - "сейчас", пожалуй, более экспрессивно.
Оно же лучше сочетается с усилительной частицей "же".

Comment: Навскидку. Я могу сказать: сейчас отвечу (приду и т.п.). Даже просто: "Сейчас, сейчас". Но можно ли сказать "теперь отвечу (приду и т.п.)? 
Похоже действительно, "сейчас"  больше связано с будущим временем, чем "теперь".

Comment: Какой-то смысл в этом есть, но словарями не фиксируется. 
То что вы говорите про будущее - это более частое употребление (по естественным причинам), но не семантика.
  
Да и не так все просто:  "Мы сейчас уже достигли этих результатов, вышли на эти показатели". "Мы сейчас прошли точку невозврата" и проч. - Ну никак не "теперь".    
  
Я бы сказал, что "сейчас" (=сей час) означает некий отрезок времени в обе стороны от настоящего момента, а "теперь" - сам такой момент, но  что-то мешает: "Я сейчас делаю что-то" и "Я сейчас далаю это" - скорее первое.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что "сейчас" (=сей час) означает некий отрезок времени в обе стороны от настоящего момента, а "теперь" - сам такой момент, но  что-то мешает: "Я сейчас делаю что-то" и "Я теперь делаю это" - скорее первое. Второе разве в ситуации, когда еще было что-то "раньше" или будет "потом".

Последнее предположние: сейчас это действительно момент (плюс-минус что-то), а вот "теперь" обязвтельнов ряду рашьше-теперь-потом, т.е. обязательно противопоставляет что-то "теперь" чему-то "раньше" или "потом". Вот с чем-то таким я бы с оговорками согласился.

Comment: Мне кажется, но слово теперь можно заменить словом уже. Со словом сейчас такой трюк не проходит.